# Two Nonpositive Hermite Matrix diagolized simultaneously

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A,B$ be two non-negative $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix, and $rank(A)=n-1$. Show that there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$, $P^{-1}BP$ both are diagonal.

I have no idea about it.

Comment: Hermite = Hermitian?  $r$ = rank?  But you didn't tell us any relation between $A$ and $B$.  If $A$ and $B$ have no eigenvectors in common, $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ can't both be diagonal.

Comment: Year. Hermitian, rank...This is a PhD entrance exam problem from China.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your statement is true, i.e., that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are both diagonal, and using the obvious fact that the diagonal matrices commute, we see that

$$AB = P (P^{-1}AP) (P^{-1}BP) P^{-1} = P (P^{-1}BP) (P^{-1}AP) P^{-1} = BA,$$

which means that $A$ and $B$ commute. In other words, if $A$ and $B$ do not commute, your statement is false, and it is easy to construct non-commuting $A$ and $B$ that conform to your requirements. For example,

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

are two non-negative (in the both possible meanings!) Hermitian matrices of rank $n-1$, but they do not commute, which - by what I've shown before - means that they cannot be simultaneously diagonalized.

The reverse (if $A$ and $B$ commute, then they can be simultaneously diagonalized) is true. For that, see the Schur decomposition of a commuting family of matrices in Notes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Notes) and apply the fact that your matrices are Hermitian.

Comment: The assumption that $A,B$ to be Hermitian and non-negativity do not help?

Comment: It helps in a way that the Schur decomposition provides diagonal instead of the usual triangular factors. But you still need the commutativity (which follows from the common eigenvectors which Robert has mentioned in the comments above).

Comment: I've added an example.